go.mod file getting updated when running go mod tidy
I have the following go.mod file. I'm unable to run the module as the compiler in VSCode asks me to run go mod tidy. When I run go mod tidy my go.mod file gets updated with go version getting bumped from 1.19 to 1.21, and a new toolchain go1.22.1 line added. go.sum file is also getting updated.
This behaviour is only happening for me and not for my colleagues (for the exactly same go.mod file), indicating that something is wrong with my setup.
Running go mod tidy -go=1.19 gives the following error -- go: google.golang.org/grpc@v1.65.0 requires go@1.21, but 1.19 is requested
I am confused so as to why this is happening, and what can I do to stop this behaviour
go.mod file :
module product-api

go 1.19

require (
    cloud.google.com/go/pubsub v1.37.0
    github.com/DataDog/datadog-go/v5 v5.2.0
    github.com/fermatcommerce/fermat/go/common v0.0.0-20220906110310-ef66faa0b8db
    github.com/fermatcommerce/fermat/go/product-svc v0.0.0-00010101000000-000000000000
    github.com/fermatcommerce/fermat/proto/product-service/go v0.0.0-00010101000000-000000000000
    github.com/go-chi/chi/v5 v5.0.8
    github.com/go-chi/cors v1.2.1
    github.com/google/uuid v1.6.0
    github.com/lib/pq v1.10.6
    github.com/shopspring/decimal v1.3.1
    github.com/stretchr/testify v1.8.4
    go.uber.org/zap v1.24.0
    golang.org/x/exp v0.0.0-20240325151524-a685a6edb6d8
    google.golang.org/protobuf v1.34.2
)

require (
    cloud.google.com/go v0.112.1 // indirect
    cloud.google.com/go/cloudsqlconn v0.5.1 // indirect
    cloud.google.com/go/compute/metadata v0.3.0 // indirect
    cloud.google.com/go/iam v1.1.6 // indirect
    github.com/Azure/go-ansiterm v0.0.0-20210617225240-d185dfc1b5a1 // indirect
    github.com/Microsoft/go-winio v0.5.2 // indirect
    github.com/Microsoft/hcsshim v0.9.4 // indirect
    github.com/cenkalti/backoff/v4 v4.1.3 // indirect
    github.com/containerd/cgroups v1.0.4 // indirect
    github.com/containerd/containerd v1.6.8 // indirect
    github.com/davecgh/go-spew v1.1.1 // indirect
    github.com/docker/distribution v2.8.1+incompatible // indirect
    github.com/docker/docker v20.10.17+incompatible // indirect
    github.com/docker/go-connections v0.4.0 // indirect
    github.com/docker/go-units v0.5.0 // indirect
    github.com/felixge/httpsnoop v1.0.4 // indirect
    github.com/go-logr/logr v1.4.1 // indirect
    github.com/go-logr/stdr v1.2.2 // indirect
    github.com/gogo/protobuf v1.3.2 // indirect
    github.com/golang/groupcache v0.0.0-20210331224755-41bb18bfe9da // indirect
    github.com/golang/protobuf v1.5.4 // indirect
    github.com/google/s2a-go v0.1.7 // indirect
    github.com/googleapis/enterprise-certificate-proxy v0.3.2 // indirect
    github.com/googleapis/gax-go/v2 v2.12.2 // indirect
    github.com/jackc/pgpassfile v1.0.0 // indirect
    github.com/jackc/pgservicefile v0.0.0-20221227161230-091c0ba34f0a // indirect
    github.com/jackc/pgx/v4 v4.17.0 // indirect
    github.com/jackc/pgx/v5 v5.5.2 // indirect
    github.com/jackc/puddle/v2 v2.2.1 // indirect
    github.com/magiconair/properties v1.8.6 // indirect
    github.com/moby/sys/mount v0.3.3 // indirect
    github.com/moby/sys/mountinfo v0.6.2 // indirect
    github.com/moby/term v0.0.0-20210619224110-3f7ff695adc6 // indirect
    github.com/morikuni/aec v1.0.0 // indirect
    github.com/opencontainers/go-digest v1.0.0 // indirect
    github.com/opencontainers/image-spec v1.0.3-0.20211202183452-c5a74bcca799 // indirect
    github.com/opencontainers/runc v1.1.3 // indirect
    github.com/pkg/errors v0.9.1 // indirect
    github.com/pmezard/go-difflib v1.0.0 // indirect
    github.com/rogpeppe/go-internal v1.12.0 // indirect
    github.com/sirupsen/logrus v1.8.1 // indirect
    github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-go v0.15.0 // indirect
    go.opencensus.io v0.24.0 // indirect
    go.opentelemetry.io/contrib/instrumentation/google.golang.org/grpc/otelgrpc v0.49.0 // indirect
    go.opentelemetry.io/contrib/instrumentation/net/http/otelhttp v0.49.0 // indirect
    go.opentelemetry.io/otel v1.24.0 // indirect
    go.opentelemetry.io/otel/metric v1.24.0 // indirect
    go.opentelemetry.io/otel/trace v1.24.0 // indirect
    go.uber.org/atomic v1.10.0 // indirect
    go.uber.org/multierr v1.9.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/crypto v0.23.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/net v0.25.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/oauth2 v0.20.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/sync v0.7.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/sys v0.20.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/text v0.15.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/time v0.5.0 // indirect
    google.golang.org/api v0.169.0 // indirect
    google.golang.org/genproto v0.0.0-20240213162025-012b6fc9bca9 // indirect
    google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/api v0.0.0-20240528184218-531527333157 // indirect
    google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/rpc v0.0.0-20240528184218-531527333157 // indirect
    google.golang.org/grpc v1.65.0 // indirect
    gopkg.in/yaml.v3 v3.0.1 // indirect
)

go env returns the following
GO111MODULE=''
GOARCH='arm64'
GOBIN=''
GOCACHE='/Users/tanmay/Library/Caches/go-build'
GOENV='/Users/tanmay/Library/Application Support/go/env'
GOEXE=''
GOEXPERIMENT=''
GOFLAGS=''
GOHOSTARCH='arm64'
GOHOSTOS='darwin'
GOINSECURE=''
GOMODCACHE='/Users/tanmay/go/pkg/mod'
GONOPROXY=''
GONOSUMDB=''
GOOS='darwin'
GOPATH='/Users/tanmay/go'
GOPRIVATE=''
GOPROXY='https://proxy.golang.org,direct'
GOROOT='/opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.22.1/libexec'
GOSUMDB='sum.golang.org'
GOTMPDIR=''
GOTOOLCHAIN='local'
GOTOOLDIR='/opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.22.1/libexec/pkg/tool/darwin_arm64'
GOVCS=''
GOVERSION='go1.22.1'
GCCGO='gccgo'
AR='ar'
CC='cc'
CXX='c++'
CGO_ENABLED='1'
GOMOD='/Users/tanmay/Desktop/fermat/go/product-api/go.mod'
GOWORK=''
CGO_CFLAGS='-O2 -g'
CGO_CPPFLAGS=''
CGO_CXXFLAGS='-O2 -g'
CGO_FFLAGS='-O2 -g'
CGO_LDFLAGS='-O2 -g'
PKG_CONFIG='pkg-config'
GOGCCFLAGS='-fPIC -arch arm64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -ffile-prefix-map=/var/folders/tk/g6yl6ybj5gz764nfsh8zrfh00000gn/T/go-build2365762375=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common'


google.golang.org/grpc@v1.65.0 requires go@1.21, but 1.19 is requested, try older version i.e. v1.40.0.


Running go mod tidy -go=1.19 gives the following error --
go: google.golang.org/grpc@v1.65.0 requires go@1.21, but 1.19 is requested

This seems to be self explanatory: You'll need at least Go 1.21 for google.golang.org/grpc 1.65.0. Upgrade your required Go version to at least 1.21 or downgrade the package, 1.64.1 is the last version compatible with Go 1.19. See also the release notes and Issue 7250

This behaviour is only happening for me and not for my colleagues (for the exactly same go.mod file), indicating that something is wrong with my setup.

This change was introduced with go 1.21:

The go line must be greater than or equal to the go line of all dependencies.

So your colleagues are using an older version of Go.

I am confused so as to why this is happening, and what can I do to stop this behaviour

Update all you Go compilers to the latest version:

Each major Go release is supported until there are two newer major releases.

So while Go 1.20 is technically still supported, Go 1.23 is expected to be released in August 2024 and support will be dropped.

`This change was introduced with go 1.21:
The go line must be greater than or equal to the go line of all dependencies.
So your colleagues are using an older version of Go.`
I didn't get it, when you say my colleagues are using an older version of go, what do you mean? Are you saying that the go version that they have installed on their system locally is something like 1.19?
But that shouldn't matter right? Isn't that the whole point of having a go.mod file?
Also, what different stuff used to happen prior to version 1.21 of go in go.mod file?

If you colleagues have Go 1.20 (still supported) installed, they won't check for “The go line must be greater than or equal to the go line of all dependencies”. Newer versions can have a toolchain line that automatically downloads newer versions, but all that is only available since Go 1.21.
Older versions made it your responsibility that the requirements for the dependencies are fulfilled and didn't check automatically, they only checked if your installed version is sufficient for the root module.

They are using go version 1.19
But then, this module should not be running successfully for them right? since the version requirements are not met?
But the module (product-api) is running successfully for them

Nothing guarantees that their program is working, but nothing guarantees that it will crash immediately. Most changes are very subtle, see “Backward Compatibility, Go 1.21, and Go 2” and ”Go, Backwards Compatibility, and GODEBUG”. TL;DR: You are in untested territory, and when developers of a package remove compatibility of an old version they won't change all code immediately. You'll get a different random implementation now, which might or might not affect your code.
